# Trying to install Python

Tags: python, installation

Whenever I try installing Python on my Laptop, it keeps failing and then says “The Windows Installer could not be accessed”
How can I fix this?

I have tried disabling Windows Update Service, tried installing from Microsoft Store (but I couldn’t run Jupyter Notebook so I had to uninstall)
I just need to know how to fix the “Windows Installer Service not being accessed” problem

Answer (score 1):

### To check if the Windows Installer Service is running:

1. On Windows, click Start > Run. (or `Win` + `R`)
2. In Open, type `services.msc` and click OK.
3. In the Services (Local) list, right-click **Windows Installer** and click **Properties**.
4. Inspect the Start Up Type box. If it is set to Disable:

   1. From the Start Up Type drop-down list, select **Manual**.
   2. In the Service Status section, click **Start**.

### To re-register the Windows Installer Service:

1. On Windows, click Start > Run. (or `Win` + `R`)
2. In Open, type `msiexec.exe /unreg` and click **OK**.
3. Click OK if a confirmation message appears.
4. On Windows, click Start > Run
5. In Open, type `msiexec.exe /regserver` and click **OK**.
6. Click OK, if a confirmation message appears.

source: https://www.autodesk.com/support/technical/article/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Error-The-Windows-Installer-Service-could-not-be-accessed-This-can-occur-if-the-Windows-Installer-is-not-correctly-installed-Contact-your-support-personnel-for-assistance-uninstalling-or-installing-Autodesk-products.html